# How to export excel file to pdf(mpdf) with utf-8

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.5.4.

I use Laravel Excel(http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) and I can export excel file to pdf with mpdf but some charecter in thai language are not expected. It's about charector in thai language. Please help.

I use this code for load and export to pdf

```
$path = 'excel\save\1\3\20180114-210116_1.xlsx';
$records = \Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
$reader->noHeading();
})->export('pdf');
```

Screenshot of Export Excel file to pdf. I think it's must be change something in mpdf but I don't know so sorry. I'm beginner.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMvvW.jpg